# JavaFX Notification of Events for Small Changes to Large Data

Tags: events, javafx, notifications

I have an **MyImage** class that is backed by an **NIO** buffer. I have a **MyHistogram** class that derives its data by iterating over the MyImage pixel data. I also have a **MyHistogramView** class which is a JavaFX `StackedAreaChart<Integer, Integer>` that is a view of a MyHistogram.

At present my MyHistogramView has a `ObjectProperty<MyHistogram>` **imageHistogram**. MyHistogramView adds a listener to the  imageHistogram property so the MyHistogramView is re-rendered whenever the whole MyHistogram is replaced. Similarly MyHistogram has a MyImage property and listener that causes the MyHistogram to be recalculated each time the MyImage property changes.

This however means that I have to create a whole new image to trigger the update of the Histogram and Histogram view when I may only  be changing a few pixels in the image.

I want an efficient strategy where I can alter one or more pixels an a MyImage, and then trigger the recalculation of MyHistogram and MyHistogramView without having to recreate any of these items.

One thought would be have an integer “revision” integer property that gets bumped after each batch of pixel altering operations. Interested parties such as MyHistogram, could listen to this and perform the recalculation whenever the revision property changes. This feels like subverting the original FX properties design though.

Any thoughts gratefully accepted!

Comment: Consider using [`ObservableIntegerArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/ObservableIntegerArray.html) in `MyImage` and/or `MyHistogram` (depending on how these are actually implemented). These have fairly fine-grained change notifications that you could probably use to make this more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately for MyImage it needs to be based on a NIO buffer as these are used for passing to JNA libraries for camera hardware to access. ObservableIntgerArray may at least be a candidate for the MyHistogram class though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing `Observable` and implementing `Observer` from the `java.util` is all I needed. Duh!